# Pandas randomly select n groups from a larger dataset

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a dataframe with groups like so

```
val label
x   A    
x   A   
x   B
x   B
x   C
x   C
x   D
x   D
```

how can I randomly pick out n groups without replacement?

Comment: It is not really clear how you would use the `for` loop to pick random items. Can you first provide equivalent *vanilla* Python code, then we can try to optimize this.

Comment: My bad. I was confusing things. Updated to reflect solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) with `loc`:

```
N = 3
vals = np.random.choice(df['label'].unique(), N, replace=False) 
print (vals)
['C' 'A' 'B']

df = df.set_index('label').loc[vals].reset_index()
print (df)
  label val
0     C  x5
1     C  x6
2     A  x1
3     A  x2
4     B  x3
5     B  x4
```

Comment: As a bonus, how would I evaluate some feature of a group (e.g. the sum of values), and discard the group if it doesn't pass the test? E.g. say I draw 1000 random groups, but the group sum for 200 of them is too low, so I discard and re-draw until I have 1000 accepted groups? I can edit my original post to include, if you know how. Or should I start a new thread?

Comment: OK, but is possible first aggregate `sum` like `s = df.groupby('lable')['val'].sum()`, then filter like `b = s[s > 200]` and then use my solution `np.random.choice(b.index, N, replace=False)` ?