# Pandas filter rows with randomly selected elements

Tags: pandas

i have a dataframe with N rows, and i'm trying to filter ONLY the rows that contain a certain randomly chosen set of values for a given column.

Example:

```
df
col1  col2 
a      1 
b      2
a      3
c      4
g      6
g      8
```

Number of values I want to randomly choose: **2** (from `col1`) -> `(a, g)`
output:

```
col1  col2 
a      1 
a      3
g      6
g      8
```

Comment: [this answer in particular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67991553)

Comment: or to select N random groups, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137324/pandas-randomly-select-n-groups-from-a-larger-dataset)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
N = 2

out = df[df['col1'].isin(np.random.choice(df['col1'].unique(), N))]
print(out)

# Output
  col1  col2
0    a     1
2    a     3
4    g     6
5    g     8
```

Comment: why not use groupby+sample like in the linked duplicate?

Comment: @mozway. I think I don't fully understand the question

Comment: maybe I don't either, many unclear questions today ;)

Comment: I don't know if the OP wants to remove all records with a length less than 2 (value_counts) or select all records from 2 randomly groups.

Comment: So I don't think the dup is the right answer :(

Comment: then it would be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137324/pandas-randomly-select-n-groups-from-a-larger-dataset)

Comment: I prefer my answer with `isin` to leave the index untouched :)